# Why Would 2 Tree Based Methods Have Different Variables Of Importance

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, random-forest, boosting

I am using the data set Boston to predict the dependent variable medv. I used two tree based methods, xgboost and random forest. Both models give me a very similar R^2 on the test data set. 
RandomForest R^2 = .81 and xgboost R^2 = .79.

When I plot the variables of importance, xgboost relies much more on the variable lstat while the random forest sees the variable rm as the most important.

Is it a common occurrence for two tree based methods like random forest and xgboost to find different relationships in the data? For another data set I have worked with, the variable importance were vastly different! Why might this be the case?
Lastly, is there a way to combine these two models to create an even better output?

Here is variable importance for xgboost
[image]

Here is variable importance for the random Forest
[image]

Comment: While there are similarities between these two algorithms they are different, one uses bagging the other uses boosting, for one.

Comment: There are two different questions here. The first is why we get different importance metrics and the second one how "*to combine these two models to create an even better output*". Which one you want to focus on?

Comment: Could you focus on how to combined them? That would be great.